# API key functions on joomla component

Tags: facebook, joomla

i am using the facebook API Key with a joomla component to make comments on articles using facebook account.

i have used a third party component JFBCONNECT to post comments, this component uses API KEY.

i want to know that is there any BACKUP or databes of that posted comments ?

if i change my joomla CMS 1.5 with joomla CMS 1.7 and install new JFBCONNECT then give the same API KEY , can i get back all the comments or not?

waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Im not sure whether the comment are stored on your server or the facebook servers so, go to you Koomla database and look for the JFBCONNECT tables, see if any of them contain the comments made. If so then make a backup, if not the they are stored on the facebook database.

Answer (score 0):

facebook comment in JFBCONNECT are stored on facebook server and associated with your app.

so if you upgrade joomla you will not loose any comment untill the url' are same.
because i think facebook manages the comment using urls as unique identifier.